# SageMath: How do I plot the sum of a deterministic variable and a random variable

Tags: statistics, plotting, probability, sage

Suppose I have the following function
$$f(x,y,z1,z2)=g(x-z1,y-z2)$$
where $g(x,y)$ is a deterministic function from the $X\times Y\to S$ and $z1,z2$ are random variables following a known probability distribution. Now, I wish to plot the distribution of $f$ over the grid of $X\times Y$. How do I do this in SageMath? Specifically, SageMath does not let me add or multiply a random variable with a deterministic variable. How to overcome this problem? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: You should edit the title to mention SageMath.